# Explain a result of "adist" function in R

Tags: r, levenshtein-distance

I have been using the "adist" function in R, it calculates the Levenshtein distance between two strings of characters. Here is a reproducible example:

```
>a <- c("bonjour", "bonsoir", "good morning", "hello world")
>b <- c("maman", "bienjoue", "printemps")

>adist(a, b, counts = TRUE)
```

the results I am getting are as follows:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    7    3    8
[2,]    7    5    8
[3,]   10   11   12
[4,]   11   10   11

attr(,"counts")

, , ins

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    1    2
[2,]    0    1    2
[3,]    0    0    1
[4,]    0    1    0

, , del

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    0    0
[2,]    2    0    0
[3,]    7    4    4
[4,]    6    4    2

, , sub

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    5    2    6
[2,]    5    4    6
[3,]    3    7    7
[4,]    5    5    9

attr(,"trafos")

     [,1]            [,2]            [,3]           
[1,] "SSSSSDD"       "MSIMMMMS"      "SSIMSSSSI"    
[2,] "SSSSSDDS"      "MSIMSMSS"      "SSIMSSSSI"    
[3,] "SSDDDMSDDDMDD" "SSSSSDMSSDDDD" "SSSSSIMSSDDDD"
[4,] "SSSSSDDDDDDD"  "SIMSSMSSDDDD"  "SSSSSSSSSDDD"
```

In the cell [4, 1] you can see it performed 6 deletions and 5 substitutions and 0 insertions, however, if you take a look at the "trafos" attribute for this cell, it displays 5 times S and 7 times D totaling 12 edits when the distance is 11 (it adds an additional D).

This is when we calculate the Levenshtein distance between "hello world" and "maman".

If I apply the "adist" directly to those two instead of being in two vectors I get the following:

```
>adist("hello world","maman",counts = TRUE)

     [,1]
[1,]   11

attr(,"counts")

, , ins

     [,1]
[1,]    0

, , del

     [,1]
[1,]    6

, , sub

     [,1]
[1,]    5

attr(,"trafos")

     [,1]         
[1,] "SSSSSDDDDDD"
```

Which seems right in this case.

What is causing this difference in results between applying "adist" to two vectors of character strings and applying it to two object (two strings)?

Comment: Great question. The same question was asked [two years ago without any answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30590126/adist-different-levenshtein-alignments-depending-on-how-the-strings-are-entered) and it looks like a bug. If you reverse, say,  `a` then you get the right string at `attr(,"trafos")[1,1]` but the others mess up. I've been looking at the C code but haven't found the reason yet

Comment: @ekstroem How can I access the C code?

Comment: Can download it from CRAN or see it [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/bf0a0a9d12f2ce5d66673dc32cd253524f3270bf/src/main/agrep.c)

Comment: Probably the C `char *` R is re-using to populate `attr(, "trafos")` is, at times, mis-terminated? Perhaps, since it is initialized with `calloc`, using `length == 1` vectors gets away with it, but populating it multiple times (when using `length > 1` vectors) returns invalid results.

Comment: FYI - https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=17579